# Socket.io Fails On Signed Android APK But Not Unsigned APK

Tags: android, node.js, https, socket.io, webrtc

I'm getting ready to release an Android app to the Play Store that has a video chat feature built with WebRTC and Socket.io. The app works perfectly in debug mode, but when I create a signed apk my app has a major problem.

The problem is that using the signed apk, I'm still able to start a video chat successfully. However if I force quit the app, and reopen it, I'm unable to start a video chat ever again.

It seems to happen because my app is unable to connect to the socket server after force quitting the app followed by reopening the app. I'm able to pinpoint the error thanks to this socket.io callback

```
socket.on('reconnect_error', (error) => {
  alert(error);
});
```

The alerted error is

> error: xhr poll error android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works well on the signed apk now. I got it to work after reading through https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Under **Common Problems Verifying Server Certificates**, one of the problems is

> The server configuration is missing an intermediate CA

It turns out that this was the issue behind the failed Socket.io calls. I went on https://www.sslshopper.com, and put in the url and port for my socket server. It told me that I have a problem with my setup. I looked back at the code for my socket server, and realized that I specified the wrong options. I forgot to include `ca` and `cert` was pointing to the wrong file. I'm using Let's Encrypt, and https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/node-js-configuration/5175
 really helped me figure out the correct options.

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/fullchain.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/chain.pem')
}

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('hello world\n');
}).listen(8000);
```